# Stop currency translation in Craft Commerce

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, currency

I’m creating a multi language site (Arabic/English) with Craft Commerce. On the Arabic cart page I output `item.total` with the help of

```
{{ item.total|commerceCurrency(cart.paymentCurrency, convert=true, format=true) }}
```

The price is output like so: "دولار أمريكي 5.00".

It translates $ to دولار أمريكي) دولار أمريكي = American dollar) and I want it to be output like so: "$5.00".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t think it is possible to stop the filter to translate the $ symbol. I don’t know Arabic, but it seems weird to me that the filter does that. If you agree you could consider sending a feature request to Pixel and Tonic.

To work around the issue now you could set the format option to false and only use the `commerceCurrency` filter to convert the value. Then format it for the output manually with help of the [`number_format`](https://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/filters/number_format.html) filter.

```
{% set total = item.total|commerceCurrency(cart.paymentCurrency, convert=true, format=false) %}

{% if cart.paymentCurrency.iso == 'usd' %}
    ${{ total|number_format(2, '.', ',') }}
{% elseif cart.paymentCurrency.iso == 'eur' %}
    {{ total|number_format(2, '.', ',') }} EUR
{% endif %}
```

Here is how you can apply the manual formatting to select currencies only.

```
{% if cart.paymentCurrency.iso == 'usd' %}
    {% set total = item.total|commerceCurrency(cart.paymentCurrency, convert=true, format=false) %}
    ${{ total|number_format(2, '.', ',') }}
{% elseif cart.paymentCurrency.iso == 'eur' %}
    {% set total = item.total|commerceCurrency(cart.paymentCurrency, convert=true, format=false) %}
    {{ total|number_format(2, '.', ',') }} EUR
{% else %}
    {{ item.total|commerceCurrency(cart.paymentCurrency, convert=true, format=true) }}
{% endif %}
```

It’s probably a good idea to use a [Twig macro](https://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/tags/macro.html) for this snippet.

Comment: Thanks Sir! But I am supposing if admin will add new payment currency then if condition will fail. I am trying to getting some dynamic solution.

Comment: Updated the answer @MohitPrajapati